# validate task form

Tags: javascript, development, office-365, csom, task-list

We are using Office 365 i am trying to validate the task form.When the user clicks on Approved move forward and approve but when user rejects the document he should fill Description for rejection.When i am trying to validate this Pre Save action is not working and when approved or rejected the Task Outcome is not getting Updated.

```
     <script language="javascript">
      $(function()
      {
     var butApproved = $("input[value='Approved']");
     var butRejected = $("input[value='Rejected']");
     var butSaveName = $("input[value='Save']").attr("name");
     var optionResult = "";

     butApproved.attr("onclick", "");
     butRejected.attr("onclick", "");

     butApproved.attr("onclick", "optionResult='Approved'; if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('" + butSaveName + "', '', true, '', '', false, true))");
      butRejected.attr("onclick", "optionResult='Rejected'; if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('" + butSaveName + "', '', true, '', '', false, true))");

        });

     function PreSaveAction()
   {
  if (optionResult == "Approved")
  {
  alert("Approved");
  return false;
  }
  else if (optionResult == "Rejected")
  {
  alert("Rejected");
  return false;
}
else
{
  alert("Something happened");
}
return true;
}
</script>
```